# Sitemap for SEO - overlay or individual page?

Tags: html, seo, sitemap

Quick question - i'm going to add a sitemap to a site I've designed - just for SEO purposes.  Is it OK for a sitemap to appear in a jquery overlay (it's only very small and could still be in a separate page).  Or is it best to keep the page seperate as a standard link?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: If you’re putting it in a jQuery overlay, do its contents appear if JavaScript is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to **keep the page separate as a standard link so that search engine crawlers will be able to scan your site's source code**. It's been debated whether they scan JavaScript, but to be sure, and for those with JavaScript turned off, try to avoid JavaScript if you're focused on SEO.

*"Crawling through lots of Javascript code makes it very difficult for them to get to the information they are really looking for, which is keywords and relevant text and information about your site. Therefore, since the crawlers have a difficult time actually finding out anything of relevance about your site, it can hurt your SEO strategy"* [*link*](http://www.seomarketingworld.com/seo-faq/javascript.php)

In addition, if you will want it for functionality, consider that some users have JavaScript disabled, meaning jQuery will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a separate page for bots, crawlers, and as a fallback for anyone with javascript turned off. Then override that link with a jquery overlay to make things pretty and fast for your human visitors. This will ensure that everyone will be given a version of your sitemap they can handle, human or bot.